# Is there an Excel Array formula that can count frequency of different values against a constant and return the value with the max frequency?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data from a database that shows how users use devices to login daily tasks. I need to `tag` each device to a specific user and decide to assign each device to the user who uses it the most.

I need to come up with a simple table like the below sample:

[image: *Sample image showing dataset and desired output*]

The source data has multiple entries by each user across multiple days and dataset can grow to 20K plus rows (so pivot table not ideal solution).

The sample dataset provided only has `~700` rows which is less than `5%` of the dataset I am working on.

*Note:*

1. I can generate list of unique device IDs but need help with column K as shown in the sample image above
2. Unique device list of full dataset will be around 2K.

In the sample file, i have generated a pivot table with unique devices as rows and users as column headers. For each user, we find count/frequency of use for each device.

I have then used an array formula to get the user with maximum frequency of use for each unique device (*column BK* of pivot summary sheet).

[image: *Sample pivot table generated*]

However, this approach is not desired as the dataset will grow over time. I need a dynamic formula that will do what the pivot table does and return the user with highest frequency for each unique device.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't use a pivot table for this showing the Top 1 user for each device by entry count. It would be far more efficient than the array formulas you'll need otherwise, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of the the below formula:

```
=INDEX(
  $B$2:$B$8,
  MATCH(
    MAX(  MMULT(  --($B$2:$B$8=TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$8)),  --($A$2:$A$8=$E$1)  )  ),
          MMULT(  --($B$2:$B$8=TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$8)),  --($A$2:$A$8=$E$1)  ),
  0))
```

In case of a tie, the User appearing first in the list is returned.

[image]

---

It works like this:

1. Create a vector that is the same length as the Device-User list and contains the count of logins for the given User on the given Device

1.1. Create a matrix: By multiplying with this one each User's value in the input will be given to all entries of that User in the output

1.2. Create a vector: Each element is one if the Device is the same as the one to which we want to determine the owner

1.3. Multiply the above two

2. Determine the maximum on this list
3. Find where this maximum value occurs first
4. Get the User name corresponding to this occurrence